# Letting variables take on random values in TikZ inside \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use variables to store a value in TikZ and do computations based on it. For instance, I want to have variables `a,b` and `c` for the following purpose in TikZ:

`\draw (a,b) circle (r)`

I should be able to assign `a,b` and `c` (these can be decimals) and the circle must be drawn at the desired location with the desired radius.

How do I go about doing this?

PS: Essentially, I want to draw 100 small circles inside a unit square at random locations. Hence, I want the variables `a`, `b` and `c` to take random values. Below is my attempt, which doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[first=0, last=1000]{lcg}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,100}{
    \def{a}{\rand\arabic{rand}}
    \def{b}{\rand\arabic{rand}}
    \draw(a/1000,b/1000) circle (0.001);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2}
\def\b{3.5}
\def\r{1}
\draw (\a,\b) circle (\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: How about just `\def\a{...}` and so on? And then `\draw (\a,\b) circle (\r);`.

Comment: @Jubobs Snap `:-)`

Comment: @Jubobs I have updated my question and is slightly different from the duplicate one.

Comment: @Jubobs [I think this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42059/defining-variables-in-tikz) answers it. Thanks